# Is there a way to collapse Django Admin Modules in the lefthand nav sidebar?

Tags: django

In a project with multiple app modules, each containing many models, the lefthand side navbar of the default Django admin page has a lot of entries which results in a lot of scrolling. Is there a way to collapse or toggle the visibility of a single module?

A cursory glance through [the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.enable_nav_sidebar) was unfruitful, but that doesn't mean it isn't there.

Comment: You can override Django admin pages. Just put index.html in your app/templates/admin. There is good article about overriding Django templates on realpython https://realpython.com/customize-django-admin-python/